# Error on qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, configuration

I'm trying to incorporate some logic for for logging into an application that we use in all our products.

The code that is being invoked (which works everywhere else) is the following:

```
@Bean(name = "licenseEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean licenseEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
        throws IOException {
    return builder.dataSource(licenseServiceDataSource()).packages("com.mycompany.ap.components.license")
            .persistenceUnit("LicensePU").build();
}
```

However, it's throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'licenseValidationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseValidationService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'licenseRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ILicenseRepository' defined in com.sick.ap.components.license.repository.ILicenseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on LicenseDBConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#bb095' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#bb095': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'licenseEntityManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/sick/ap/components/license/configuration/LicenseDBConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'licenseEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

What it boils down to is this:

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'licenseEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here is the code which attempts to instantiate the EntityManagerFactoryBuilder:

```
@Bean(name = "licenseEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean licenseEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder)
        throws IOException {
    return builder.dataSource(licenseServiceDataSource()).packages("com.mycompany.ap.components.license")
            .persistenceUnit("LicensePU").build();
}
```

This corresponding dependency is included in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have made almost an exact copy of the configuration class. Here's the one from the working  app:

```
package com.workingapp.workingapp.configuration;

import com.workingapp.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.configuration.ApLoginWebConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;

/** The Class WebConfiguration. */
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends ApLoginWebConfig {

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see
   * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#
   * addViewControllers(
   * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry)
   *
   */
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}").setViewName("forward:/");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/**/*")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/")
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(
            new PathResourceResolver() {
              @Override
              protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location)
                  throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable()
                    ? requestedResource
                    : new ClassPathResource("/public/index.html");
              }
            });
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
  }
}
```

And here's mine, which is an exact copy except for the name:

```
package com.license.gen.app.config;


import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.configuration.ApLoginWebConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;

/** The Class WebConfiguration. */
@Configuration
public class LicenseAppConfiguration extends ApLoginWebConfig {

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see
   * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#
   * addViewControllers(
   * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry)
   *
   */
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}").setViewName("forward:/");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(
                    new PathResourceResolver() {
                      @Override
                      protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location)
                              throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable()
                                ? requestedResource
                                : new ClassPathResource("/public/index.html");
                      }
                    });
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
  }
}
```

This is the class that both of the above extend:

```
package com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.model.audit.ApLoginAuditorAwareImpl;
import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.security.ApLoginDatabaseConfig;
import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.security.ApLoginOAuth2ServerConfiguration;
import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.security.ApLoginWebSecurityConfiguration;
import com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.util.ApLoginUtility;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ ApLoginOAuth2ServerConfiguration.class, ApLoginWebSecurityConfiguration.class, 
    ApLoginDatabaseConfig.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.repository" }, 
        transactionManagerRef = "loginModuleMysqlTransactionManager", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "loginModuleEntityManagerBean")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
@PropertySource("classpath:login-module.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule")
public class ApLoginWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApLoginWebConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loginModuleComponentDataSource")
    private DataSource loginModuleComponentDataSource;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOGGER.info("Initializing Login and User Management database transaction management");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ApLoginUtility apLoginUtil() {
        return new ApLoginUtility();
    }

    @Bean(name = "loginModuleEntityManagerBean")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean loginModuleEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(loginModuleComponentDataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.model", 
                "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.service", 
                "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.security",
                "com.mycompany.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.validators"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("lumpPU");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }

    /**
     * Login Module transaction manager.
     *
     * @param entityManagerFactory
     *            the entity manager factory
     * @return the platform transaction manager
     */
    @Bean(name = "loginModuleMysqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("loginModuleEntityManagerBean") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new ApLoginAuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the spring boot starter class from the working app:

```
package com.mycompany.workingapp.configuration;

import com.mycompany.workingapp.ruleengine.starter.ApplicationStarter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hsqldb.Server;
import org.hsqldb.server.ServerAcl;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner.Mode;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 *
 *
 * <h2>Application Class is the entry point or the starter class for the Product</h2>
 *
 * <h3>Product development team should refrain from modifying this class. Rather use components
 * under package com.mycompany.workingapp.components package as entry point for the platfrom layers.</h3>
 *
 * <p><b> Usage</b>
 *
 * <p>To have an starter Class for Spring Boot application (Executable Jar) <br>
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.dacq.core",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.mediaserver",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.loginmodule",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.configuration",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.i18nl10n",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.license",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.decryption",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.encryption",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.geolocation",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.decryptor",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.encryptor",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp",
      "com.mycompany.il.commons.dao.hibernate.config.repository",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.hibernate",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.service.hibernate",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.hibernate.config.repository",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.el.*",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.nodered",
      "com.mycompany.ut.pubsub.*",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.mqtt.client",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.broker",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.ruleEngine",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.dataacquisitionandcontrol.configuration"
    })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.mycompany.workingapp.mysql", "com.mycompany.workingapp.dao", "com.mycompany.workingapp.preference.repository"},
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@PropertySource({
  "file:./config/application.properties",
  // "file:./config/loginModuleConfig.properties",
  // "file:./config/mysqldb.properties",
  // "file:./config/geolocationmysqldb.properties",
  "file:./config/global_settings.properties",
  "file:./config/ddMessages.properties",
  "file:./config/bip-services.properties",
  "file:./config/oee.properties",
  "file:./config/mqtt.properties",
  "file:./config/wibu.properties",
  "file:./config/mediaserverconfiguration.properties",
  "file:./config/sms.properties",
  "file:./config/email.properties",
  "file:./config/backupconfiguration.properties",
  "file:./config/tcpserver.properties"
})
public class Application {

  /** The Constant LOG. */
  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
  /** The context. */
  private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  public static String STARTING_WORKING_APP_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Starting Working App ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
  public static String WORKING_APP_STARTUP_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Working App is Running ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
  public static String WORKING_APP_STARTUP_ERROR_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x- Working App FAILED to startup and encountered Errors. Contact MyCompany with logs for technical support -x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-";
  private static Server server = null;

  /**
   * Starter Main method of Application.
   *
   * @param args String [] of command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logStartupMessage(STARTING_WORKING_APP_LOG_MESSAGE, null);

    try {
      SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
      System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
      System.setProperty("spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding", "true");
      app.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF); // Disable banner
      addInitHooks(app);
      setContext(app.run(args));
      logStartupMessage(WORKING_APP_STARTUP_LOG_MESSAGE, null);
      getContext().getBean(ApplicationStarter.class).init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logStartupMessage(WORKING_APP_STARTUP_ERROR_LOG_MESSAGE + "{}", e);
    }
  }

  static void addInitHooks(SpringApplication application) {
    application.addListeners(
        (ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>)
            event -> {
              if (event.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.profiles.active").contains("hsql")) {
                LOG.error("Starting HSQL server...");
                if (server == null) {
                  server = new Server();
                  try {
                    server.setProperties(fetchProperties());
                    server.setSilent(true);
                    server.setLogWriter(null);
                    server.start();
                  } catch (IOException | ServerAcl.AclFormatException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error in Starting HSQL server {}", e.getMessage());
                  }

                  LOG.error("HSQL server started on Address {}", server.getAddress());
                }
              }
            });
    application.addListeners(
        (ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>)
            event -> {
              if (server != null) {
                LOG.error("Stopping HSQL server...");
                server.signalCloseAllServerConnections();
                server.stop();
                server.shutdown();
              }
            });
  }

  public static Properties fetchProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    File file = new File("./config/hsql-server.properties");
    if (!file.exists()) {
      LOG.error("hsql-server.properties file not found ");
    }
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.error("Error Loading hsql-server.properties  {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return properties;
  }

  private static void logStartupMessage(String message, Exception e) {
    System.out.println(message); // NOSONAR: intentional.

    if (e == null) {
      LOG.info(message);
    } else {
      LOG.error(message, e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the context.
   *
   * @return the application context
   */
  public static final ConfigurableApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the context.
   *
   * @param context the context to set
   */
  private static void setContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    Application.context = context;
  }
}
```

And here it is from mine, almost an exact copy, but with unneeded properties file commented out and this line:

```
      getContext().getBean(ApplicationStarter.class).init();
```

commented out (it only runs some database partitioning).

```
package com.mycompany.workingapp.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hsqldb.Server;
import org.hsqldb.server.ServerAcl;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner.Mode;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 *
 *
 * <h2>Application Class is the entry point or the starter class for the Product</h2>
 *
 * <h3>Product development team should refrain from modifying this class. Rather use components
 * under package com.mycompany.workingapp.components package as entry point for the platform layers.</h3>
 *
 * <p><b> Usage</b>
 *
 * <p>To have a starter Class for Spring Boot application (Executable Jar) <br>
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.dacq.core",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.mediaserver",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.loginmodule",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.configuration",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.i18nl10n",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.license",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.decryption",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.encryption",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.services.geolocation",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.decryptor",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.encryptor",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp",
      "com.mycompany.il.commons.dao.hibernate.config.repository",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.hibernate",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.service.hibernate",
      "com.mycompany.ilcore.dao.hibernate.config.repository",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.el.*",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.nodered",
      "com.mycompany.ut.pubsub.*",
      "com.mycompany.bip.components.mqtt.client",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.broker",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.components.ruleEngine",
      "com.mycompany.workingapp.dataacquisitionandcontrol.configuration"
    })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.mycompany.workingapp.mysql", "com.mycompany.workingapp.dao", "com.mycompany.workingapp.preference.repository"},
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@PropertySource({
  "file:./config/application.properties"
  // "file:./config/loginModuleConfig.properties",
  // "file:./config/mysqldb.properties",
  // "file:./config/geolocationmysqldb.properties",
//        "file:./config/global_settings.properties",
//        "file:./config/ddMessages.properties",
//        "file:./config/bip-services.properties",
//        "file:./config/oee.properties",
//        "file:./config/mqtt.properties",
//        "file:./config/wibu.properties",
//        "file:./config/mediaserverconfiguration.properties",
//        "file:./config/sms.properties",
//        "file:./config/email.properties",
//        "file:./config/backupconfiguration.properties",
//        "file:./config/tcpserver.properties"
})
public class Application {

  /** The Constant LOG. */
  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
  /** The context. */
  private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  public static String STARTING_WORKING_APP_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Starting License App ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
  public static String WORKING_APP_STARTUP_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ License App is Running ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
  public static String WORKING_APP_STARTUP_ERROR_LOG_MESSAGE =
      "-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x- License App FAILED to startup and encountered Errors. Contact MyCompany with logs for technical support -x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-";
  private static Server server = null;

  /**
   * Starter Main method of Application.
   *
   * @param args String [] of command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logStartupMessage(STARTING_WORKING_APP_LOG_MESSAGE, null);

    try {
      SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
      System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
      System.setProperty("spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding", "true");
      app.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF); // Disable banner
      addInitHooks(app);
      setContext(app.run(args));
      logStartupMessage(WORKING_APP_STARTUP_LOG_MESSAGE, null);
      //getContext().getBean(ApplicationStarter.class).init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      logStartupMessage(WORKING_APP_STARTUP_ERROR_LOG_MESSAGE + "{}", e);
    }
  }

  static void addInitHooks(SpringApplication application) {
    application.addListeners(
        (ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>)
            event -> {
              if (event.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.profiles.active").contains("hsql")) {
                LOG.error("Starting HSQL server...");
                if (server == null) {
                  server = new Server();
                  try {
                    server.setProperties(fetchProperties());
                    server.setSilent(true);
                    server.setLogWriter(null);
                    server.start();
                  } catch (IOException | ServerAcl.AclFormatException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error in Starting HSQL server {}", e.getMessage());
                  }

                  LOG.error("HSQL server started on Address {}", server.getAddress());
                }
              }
            });
    application.addListeners(
        (ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>)
            event -> {
              if (server != null) {
                LOG.error("Stopping HSQL server...");
                server.signalCloseAllServerConnections();
                server.stop();
                server.shutdown();
              }
            });
  }

  public static Properties fetchProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    File file = new File("./config/hsql-server.properties");
    if (!file.exists()) {
      LOG.error("hsql-server.properties file not found ");
    }
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.error("Error Loading hsql-server.properties  {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return properties;
  }

  private static void logStartupMessage(String message, Exception e) {
    System.out.println(message); // NOSONAR: intentional.

    if (e == null) {
      LOG.info(message);
    } else {
      LOG.error(message, e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the context.
   *
   * @return the application context
   */
  public static final ConfigurableApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the context.
   *
   * @param context the context to set
   */
  private static void setContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    Application.context = context;
  }
}
```

I just need to either get rid of the dependency or include it. It would be better to include so I could use the common code as is. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966956/required-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-boot-orm-jpa-entitymanagerfactorybu maybe this I had commented. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I'm not sure what the fix was.